# Error with dbWriteTable when column is truncated in mutate; works fine without mutate

Tags: r, sql-server, odbc, stringr, dbi

I've got an interesting problem. I have a tibble that I would like to write to the database. When I use the code following code it works fine:

```
dbWriteTable(conn, "table_name", x_tbl)
```

But in the tibble, I've got a remark column that I would like to limit in size. In my case, the string should be a max of 1000 characters. To do this I do the following:

```
x_tbl <- x_tbl %>% mutate (remark = remark %>% str_trunc(1000, side="left")
dbWriteTable(conn, "table_name", x_tbl)
```

When I execute that code, I get the following error message from SQL SERVER:

```
Error in result_insert_dataframe(rs@ptr, values, batch_rows) : 
  nanodbc/nanodbc.cpp:1655: 22001: [Microsoft][ODBC SQL Server Driver]String data, right truncation
```

I have used various other methods to limit the lenght of the string; those include `str_sub()` and `strsub()`.

Does anybody have an idea what causes this and how to resolve it?

Comment: What is the data type of the `remark` column? Are you using `varchar` with UTF-8 encoding? Remember that UTF-8 encoding potentially expands the length of string data, with some high-valued Unicode code points requiring up to 7 bytes in a varchar field, so a string with 1,000 international code points would easily exceed a `varchar(1000)` column.

Comment: When I execute the `dbWriteTable()` command the table doesn't exist. This is the same in both cases. It would create a `varchar`.